# Function whose support lies in neighborhood of point, then a function exists and is well defined

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am self studying the book Analysis on Manifolds, and saw this problem in chapter 16. I was wondering how one would do this.

Let $S$ be an arbitrary subset of $\mathbf{R}^{n} ;$ let $x_{0} \in S .$ We say that the function $f: S \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{x}_{0},$ of class $C^{r},$ provided there is a $C^{r}$ function $g: U \rightarrow R$ defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $x_{0}$ in $\mathbf{R}^{n},$ such that $g$ agrees with $f$ on the set $U \cap S .$ In this case, show that if $\phi: \mathbf{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is a $C^{r}$ function whose support lies in $U,$ then the function
$$
h(\mathbf{x})=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\phi(\mathbf{x}) g(\mathbf{x}) & \text { for } \mathbf{x} \in U \\
0 & \text { for } \mathbf{x} \notin \text { Support } \phi
\end{array}\right.
$$
is well-defined and of class $C^{r}$ on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:   This'll work because the product of  $C^r $ functions on an open set $U$ is $C^r $ on $U $.  So use $\hat g:=\phi\cdot g:U\to\mathbb R $ in the definition.

The complement of the support of  $\phi $ is open,  so for $x\notin U $, there's an open set  $V $ on which  $h\equiv0$.